# Create output with differences between files [.BAT]

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv, cmd

I'm trying to compare the characters inside a txt file against ALL .OK files in a folder. So far it is possible to compare it against a single file but I can't find a way of doing it for MULTIPLE files. Can someone help me? THanks in advance!

```
( for /f "delims=" %%i in (E:\CSV\TEST.txt) do (
    findstr /C:"%%i" "E:\CSV\CSV.OK"  >nul || echo %%i
  )
)>E:\CSV\OUT.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
( for /f "delims=" %%i in (E:\CSV\TEST.txt) do (
    findstr /C:"%%i" "E:\CSV\*.OK"  >nul || echo %%i
  )
)>E:\CSV\OUT.csv
```

should do what you've asked.

Now - whether that's what you want, only the Doctor knows...

Comment: Hahaha yeah that's exactly what I was looking for! Even Daleks have programming questions! :)